# Do i need to make use setter or constructor in DAO implemetaion

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have the class userDAOimpl and i was using

```
@Resource(name="sessionFactory")
public SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

i want to ask that beside that do i need to use setter like

```
public void setSessionfactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
```

or

```
public DAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
```

One thing is confusing me that how will these get called

Comment: Have you heard of a term called dependency injection?

Comment: i am in the process of learning that , but now confused

Answer (score 1):

Does it make sense to have a DAOImpl instance without session factory. If it doesn't make sense, then it should be in the constructor. This way, a DAOImpl instance is in a valid state once constructed, and is never in an invalid state.

Edit : the session factory should be private, not public.

Comment: I am using spring and i ahve sessionfactory bean . ACtually i am confused because initially i was not using any of above and my code was still working

Comment: You use field injection. This means that Spring instantiates your DAOImpl using its no-arg constructor, and then uses reflection to initialize the sessionfactory field. This is OK, but makes you DAOImpl unusable outside of Spring (and thus difficult to test), since using "standard" Java code, you can't pass a session factory to your DAOImpl. Hence the need for a constructor or setter.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you are using **Property based** or **constructor based** dependency injection. ie.

If you are using Property based then setter is required.

or

If you are using Constructor based then in constructor is required

Comment: He seems to be using field-based injection.